# Обучение парсингу сайтов

Tags: c#, html, синтаксический-анализ

Всем привет!
В процессе работы возникла необходимость научиться парсить сайты. Из языков программирования чуть чуть знаю c#, в HTML-коде разбираться, к сожалению, не умею.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что читать, чтобы достаточно быстро научиться парсить сайты с помощью c#?

Answer (score 4):

Для начала нам надо получить заветную страничку. Для этого можете воспользоваться такими классами как [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) (что гибче) или [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) (что проще). Так же надо понимать что такое [GET](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#GET) и [POST](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#POST) запросы, [cookies (в простонародье "куки")](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) и [Headers (заголовки)](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Заголовки_HTTP).

Страничку мы получили. Теперь ее, собственно, парсим. Для этого можно воспользоваться такими библиотеками как [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) или [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery). Лично я бы посоветовал последнюю. Так же могут пригодиться [регулярные выражения](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx). Вот в общем то и все

И еще. Чтобы смотреть какие запросы отправляет браузер, вам нужен какой-нибудь веб-дебаггер. В принципе в популярных браузерах есть "инструмент разработчика" (или как он там называется), но на мой взгляд удобнее это делать через [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)